# Paging and Join in Room

Tags: android, android-studio, android-room, multimap

I want to use **[paging](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging/v3-overview?hl=th)** in room But I can not. Because I use **[multimap](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/relationships#multimap)** and it return map. When I use these technology together, I get this error :

```
error: Not sure how to convert a Cursor to this method's return type
```

Here is my code :

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM table_1 JOIN table_2 ON table_1.domain = table_2.domain)
DataSource.Factory<Integer, Map<Table1Entity, Table2Entity>> getAllData();
```

Comment: Did you found any solution for that?

Comment: No , I do not know how to solve it !

Comment: You're going to have to add a Type converter to convert the provided type to json.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, but as a result I had to revise the tables and use the advice of Mbuodile Obiosio.

I have something like this json response:

```
{
        "id": 1,
        "parent_data": "...",
        "child_data": [
        {
            "id": 2,
            "parent_id": 1,
            "mediaFiles": [
            {
                "mediaFile": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/picture1.png"
            },
            {
                "mediaFile": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/picture2.png"
            }
            ]
        }
        ]
    }
```

Using TypeConverter, the nested data was converted to Json.

```
class ChildConverter{
   @TypeConverter
   fun toString(items: List<ChildModel>): String = Gson().toJson(items)

   @TypeConverter
   fun toChildModel(json: String): List<ChildModel>
   {
      val type: Type = object : TypeToken<List<ChildModel>>(){}.type
      return Gson().fromJson(json, type)
   }
}

class MediaFilesConverter{
   @TypeConverter
   fun toString(items: List<MediaFilesModel>): String = Gson().toJson(items)

   @TypeConverter
   fun toMedia(json: String): List<MediaFilesModel>
   {
      val type: Type = object : TypeToken<List<MediaFilesModel>>(){}.type
      return Gson().fromJson(json, type)
   }
}
```

Data class:

```
@Entity(tableName = "parent")
data class ParentData (
   @PrimaryKey
   @field:SerializedName("id") val id: Int,
   @field:SerializedName("parent_data") val parent_data: String,
   @TypeConverters(ChildConverter::class)
   @field:SerializedName("child_data") var child_data: List<ChildData>
)

data class ChildData(
   @SerializedName("id") val id: Int,
   @SerializedName("parent_id") val parent_id: Int,
   @TypeConverters(MediaFilesConverter::class)
   @SerializedName("mediaFiles") var media: List<MediaFile>
)

data class MediaFile(
   @SerializedName("mediaFile")
   val mediaURL: String
)
```

Dao:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM parent")
fun getParentList(): PagingSource<Int, ParentData>
```

Database:

```
@Database(entities = [ParentData::class, ...],
        version = 1,
        exportSchema = false)
@TypeConverters(
        ChildConverter::class,
        MediaFilesConverter::class)
abstract class MyDataBase: RoomDatabase() 
{...}
```